# Creating function in python for averages?

Tags: python

I am stuck - need some help to get started - just hitting a brick wall.

So there are supposed to be two lists and one table defined as follows.

• Actors, a list of strings that are actor names. For each i such that 0 ≤ i ≤ len(Actors) − 1, we refer to Actor[i] as the i-th actor.

• Films, a list of strings that are film names. For each i such that 0 ≤ i ≤ len(Films) − 1, we refer to Film[i] as the i-th film.

• Scores, a table whose rows correspond to the actors and columns correspond to the films. Scores[i][j] is an integer number defined as follows.

– If Scores[i][j] = −1 this means that the i-th actor is not a star for the j-th film.

– If Scores[i][j] ≥ 0 then this is the score of the i-th actor for the j-th film. You can assume that the scores are in range 0-100, there is no need to check the validity of the data.

I am allowed to define the above structures as fixed in my program, there is no need to request the user to enter them.

So how do I write a function whose arguments are a table A of integer numbers and a positive integer number i. The function should return the average of non-negative entries of A[i] (the row i of A).

Thanks Jemma

Comment: You might need  a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements); this is how you [define a function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions); [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) will help you.  Your table could be a list of lists - here is how [lists](work](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Try something. Write down in words how you think the problem can be solved - refer to this and revise as needed. Break the problem up into smaller problems and try to solve those one at at time. Come back here with issues you encounter with solving the smaller problems.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

actors = ['Brad Pitt', 'George Clooney', 'Matt Damon', 'Rowan Atkinson']

films = ['Oceans 11', 'Oceans 12', 'Bean']

actors_dimension = (len(actors))

longest_actor_length = len(max(actors, key=len))
longest_film_length = len(max(films, key=len))
longest_overall_length = max(longest_actor_length, longest_film_length)
padding = longest_overall_length

scores_width = len(films) + 1
scores_height = len(actors) + 1

scores = [[' '.rjust(padding) for x in range(scores_width)] for y in range(scores_height)]

#Setting films
for i, film in enumerate(films):
  scores[0][i+1] = film.rjust(padding)

#Setting actors
for i, actor in enumerate(actors):
  scores[i+1][0] = actor.rjust(padding)

#Filling data
#Brad Pitt
scores[1][1] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[1][2] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[1][3] = '-1'.rjust(padding)

#George Clooney
scores[2][1] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[2][2] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[2][3] = '-1'.rjust(padding)

'Matt Damon'
scores[3][1] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[3][2] = '1'.rjust(padding)
scores[3][3] = '-1'.rjust(padding)

'Rowan Atkinson'
scores[4][1] = '-1'.rjust(padding)
scores[4][2] = '-1'.rjust(padding)
scores[4][3] = '1'.rjust(padding)

def average_of_row(row):
  if((row > actors_dimension) or (row <= 0 )):
    print('That row is not in the table or has no actor')
  else:
    actor = (scores[:][row]).pop(0).strip()
    actors_scores = [int(x) for x in ((scores[:][row]))]
    print("%s's average score is: %f" % (actor, float((sum(actors_scores) / len(actors_scores)))))

print(np.matrix(scores))

average_of_row(1) #Brad Pitt
average_of_row(4) #Rowan Atkinson
```

**Output:**

```
[['              ' '     Oceans 11' '     Oceans 12' '          Bean']
 ['     Brad Pitt' '             1' '             1' '            -1']
 ['George Clooney' '             1' '             1' '            -1']
 ['    Matt Damon' '             1' '             1' '            -1']
 ['Rowan Atkinson' '            -1' '            -1' '             1']]
Brad Pitt's average score is: 0.333333
Rowan Atkinson's average score is: -0.333333
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/E8qE/1)

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful - has got me thinking and coding. Thank you very much